# Deploying Web API with a setup

Tags: deployment, asp.net-web-api, installation

Is there a manual for deploying an asp.net web api project?

Do I have to deploy the web api dll's or are they included in .Net 4.5?
That about JSON.NET? It seems not to be a component of .Net 4.5. Do I have to copy this ddl's on my own and what can you say me about the licensing of JSON.NET?

JSON.NET has a MIT license. What do I have to do if I want to use JSON.NET in my web api?